# AviSynth - turn sound off

Tags: avisynth

I am using AviSynth+ and I play an .avs script into VLC (I've installed the AviSynth plugin for VLC).

My script is very basic and it looks like this:

```
DirectShowSource("D:\MyVideo.asf", fps=25, convertfps=true)
```

How can I turn off the sound of the video, only for the first two minutes of the video?

I am using Windows 8 - 64 bit

Comment: http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Splice

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a very late answer, but an easy way to do it would be to split the clip into two segments, silence the first segment with `Amplify`, and then rejoin them:

```
original = DirectShowSource("D:\MyVideo.asf", fps=25, convertfps=true)
numSeconds = 60 * 2
numFrames = Round(source.FrameRate() * numSeconds)
beginning = source.Trim(0, numFrames - 1, False)
rest = source.Trim(numFrames, 0, False)

beginning.Amplify(0.0) + rest
```